# How to edit .env files in PhpStorm?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, phpdotenv

I generated new `.env` file with `copy .env.example .env` command in PhpStorm terminal. Then created .env file then but I can't edit in PhpStorm. When I double clicked it's open external editor (Notepad++).

[image: unvariable file type]

Comment: This is really strange. I open thos file normally in PhpStorm without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to file -> settings -> Editor -> File Types -> Recognized file types and select the "Text" -> add some patterns

```
.evn
*.env
.evn.*
*.env.*
```

Answer (score 16):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`
2. Find `Files Opened in Associated Application` entry in the top list
3. Remove associated entry for `.env` files from the bottom list (Registered Patterns).
4. Re-associate such pattern with another (more appropriate) File Type  (e.g. "Text Files" .. or whatever other format that would be)

---

**P.S.** There is **.​env files support plugin** that adds file icon & syntax coloring for `.env` files and code completion helper in certain languages (PHP in particular):

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9525--env-files-support

> Features:
>
> - Environment variables completion based on .env, Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml files.
> - Go to declaration (in .env file) and usages(in code), by <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd + Click</kbd> or hot key (<kbd>Ctrl / Cmd + B</kbd>, etc.)
> - .env file syntax highlighter

---

**UPDATE: 2022-01-13**

For the modern IDE versions (v2020.3.x and newer) check the following StackOverflow answer. The IDE now has more options that can affect the way how IDE treats specific file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65701638/783119

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for .env files. It also helps by autocompleting env() and getenv() functions.
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9525--env-files-support