# WebStorm File association system does not recognize a file

Tags: vue.js, webstorm

I have this Vue file with the name `SetupObjects.vue`, but it does not get associated with Vue syntax as the others are. Here is what I have tried to do:

1. Deleted it, recreated it
2. Deleted it, recreated it on another folder
3. Deleted it, recreated it on another project

No matter what I do, the file does not get its correct association.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you have created that file using wrong action or made a mistake during that process, e.g.:

- used `File | New | File...`
- did not enter the file extension there (only file name part) .. or that was a wrong yet unknown extension
- then in the popup dialog just automatically pressed Enter.

[image]

### Solution:

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`
2. Check the following file type entries:

   - `Auto-detect file type by content`
   - `Text`
   - `Files opened in associated applications` (not your case here)
3. Locate and remove unwanted pattern: will be `SetupObjects.vue` or very similar to that.

[image]

*[Source](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207062135/comments/360002575820) (PhpStorm Forums thread, a bit more details)*