# PHP file losing PHP properties in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I do not know why, but in PhpStorm (version 2021.2) one of my php files
lost php properties:
[image: PhpStorm]

And many functions of php are not applied...

Googling I found hints that I have to right-click on this file and select an option like “Mark as php.”
But I did not find such option in PhpStorm...

How can I restore it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to use "Override file type" from the context menu?

Comment: I think it is better to properly fix it (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65701638/783119) rather then create a hardcoded override (that is IDE-wide and based on an absolute file path).

Comment: Where from "Override file type" option available? I did not find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an `Override file type` option when you right-click the file

[image: Override File Type Option]

And then you can select `PHP`.

[image: Override File Type Menu]

As a "more permanent" solution you might want to check the `File Types` in `Settings`, under `Editor`, and try to see if there's something weird there.

[image: File Types Settings]

*You might want to check @LazyOne comment, which contains a [SOF post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65700794/webstorm-file-association-system-does-not-recognize-a-file/65701638#65701638), it might be useful. I also want to say thanks to him for pointing that out and give him credits for the post.*

Comment: Where from "Override file type" option available? I did not find it...

Comment: @PetroGromovo You should have it when you right-click the file in the `Project` menu, on the left. If you don't see it maybe you can associate a key to it in `Keymap` in `Settings`. You have an option there called `Override file type`.